# How to prove that this type of function is analytic

Tags: complex-analysis

I have the function
$$F(z)=\int_{\Bbb R}f(z,t)\ dt$$
$z\mapsto f(z,t)$ is analytic. How can I prove $F$ is analytic?

We assume that the integral exists.

I wanted to show it is derivable by using the theorem of derivation under the $\int$ sign but I don't think I can apply it to functions of a complex variable as I can to functions of real variables.

(In general I guess $F$ will not be analytic, but I want to have some techniques to prove if it is analytic. Which theorem can help me here for example)

Comment: Can we assume that the integral exists ?

Comment: Yes we assume it exists

Comment: A related post: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/439866/holomorphic-parameter-integral

Comment: Usually Morera's theorem is more convenient than differentiating under the integral.

Comment: In fact my main question will be : can I use the theorem of derivation under the integral sign to proove it ? (The theorem usually used with functions of the real variable).